# Microsoft Word IF formula

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-word

I am having trouble with my IF formula in Microsoft Word, I am trying to automatically output a phrase depending on if cell in my table (J2) is equal to, less than, or greater than 0.

```
=IF([J2]=0.0,"yes",IF([J2]>0,"no",IF([J2]<0,"maybe")))
```

[image: Here is my table I am trying to add the formula to]

Comment: Try actually bookmarking your cells and using the bookmark names. Since these are legacy formfields, they already have bookmark names. Use the option to calculate on exit.